# Is chat available to Xbox Live Free?

Tags: xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

I've read [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100111165954AAt5mFt) that chat is free with Xbox Live Silver (now called Xbox Live Free?).  Is this true or not?  It seems on [other sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live#Xbox_Live_features) that Xbox Live Gold is required.  And if it is true in any sense does that apply to in-game chat like what is available in Minecraft?  Is there a private chat mode that is different from the party chat mode?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live#Xbox_Live_features

Comment: yes, i saw that, but i was confused because i read somewhere there was a private to private chat mode too.  i didn't know if that was different from party chat

Comment: Party chat requires a gold membership.

Comment: There is private chat under chat & IM on 360 by pushing the xbox button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using private chat you can chat one to one with another player. You require a gold membership to play online and to chat in a party(Party chat 8 people or so) although some games allow you to be joined or play on weekends etc...
As noted at the end of the page on " http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/live" *IMPORTANT! Xbox Live Gold no longer required for some apps and features, including Twitch, Skype and YouTube.

Comment: Did not mean to do two answers, edited and this was the result(mobile platform).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't chat or message with a Silver account, all online play is restricted to Gold members only.